# Indexing numpy array as slow as python append

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

I have always been told that python's native append is a slow function and should be avoided in for loops. However after a couple of small tests I have found it performs more poorly than a numpy array when iterating over it with a for loop:

## First Test -array/list construction

#### python native list append

```
def pythonAppend(n):
      x = []
      for i in range(n):
          x.append(i)
      return x

%timeit pythonAppend(1000000)
```

#### Numpy allocate array then access

```
 def  numpyConstruct(n):
     x = np.zeros(n)
     for i in range(n):
         x[i] = i
     return x

%timeit numpyConstruct(1000000)
```

### Results:

**Python Time:** 179 ms

**Numpy Time:** 189 ms

## Second Test -Accesing Elements

```
n = 1000000
x = pythonAppend(n)
arr = numpyConstruct(n)
order = arr[:]; np.random.shuffle(order); order = list(order.astype(int))

def listAccess(x):
     for i in range(len(x)):
             x[i] = i/3.
     return x

def listAccessOrder(x, order):
     for i in order:
             x[i] = i/3.
     return x

%timeit listAccess(x)
%timeit listAccess(arr)
%timeit listAccessOrder(x, order)
%timeit listAccessOrder(arr, order)
%timeit arr / 3.
```

### Results

**python -sequential:** 175 ms

**numpy -sequential:** 198 ms

**python -shuffled access:** 2.08 s

**numpy -shuffled access:** 2.15 s

**numpy -vectorised access:** 1.92ms

---

These results to me are quite surprising as I would have thought that at least due to python being linked lists accessing elements would be slower than numpy due to having to follow a chain of pointers. Or am I misunderstanding the python list implementation? Also why do the python lists perform slightly better than the numpy equivalents -I guess most of the inefficiency comes from using a python for loop but python's append still out-competes numpy accessing and allocating.

Comment: I guess when you loose numpy in a loop you loss all the performance advantages. But if you can write it as an vector function its going to be faster then looping with clean python.

Comment: I thought numpy arrays were sequential? So accessing their elements (especially in a random order) would be faster as the CPU can grab the chunk of memory straight away rather than having to follow a sequence of pointers to the element?

Comment: python lists are not linked lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python lists are not linked lists.  The data buffer of the list object contains links/pointers to objects (else where in memory).  So fetching the `ith` element is easy.  The buffer also has growth headroom, so `append` is a simple matter of inserting the new element's link.  The buffer has to be reallocated periodically, but Python manages that seamlessly.

A numpy array also has a 1d data buffer, but it contains numeric values (more generally the bytes as required by the `dtype`).  Fetching is easy, but it has to create a new python object to 'contain' the value ('unboxing'). Assignment also requires conversion from the python object to bytes that will be stored.

Generally we've found that making a new array by appending to a list (with one `np.array` call at the end) is competitive with assignment to a preallocated array.

Iteration through a numpy array is normally slower than iterating through a list.

What we strongly discourage is using `np.append` (or some variant) to grow an array iteratively.  That makes a new array each time, with full copy.

numpy arrays are fast when the iteration is done in the compiled code.  Normally that's with the whole-array methods.  The `c` code can iterate over the data buffer, operating on the values directly, rather than invoking python object methods at each step.